# Getting started with realm ReactExample - Error no such file GCDWebServerRequest.m?

Tags: react-native, realm

I ran across realm when researching options for an embedded database to use for my first react-native app.

Following the steps documented here:
https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#examples

I entered the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/realm/realm-js.git
cd realm-js/examples/ReactExample
npm install
```

When I open ReactExample.xcodeproj and attempt to build:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/edward3/Documents/projects/react-native/realm/realm-js/vendor/GCDWebServer/GCDWebServer/Core/GCDWebServerRequest.m'
clang: error: no input files
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I was missing **git submodule update.**

```
git clone https://github.com/realm/realm-js.git
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd realm-js/examples/ReactExample
npm install
```

I am excited about learning to use realm.  The realm example, at first glance, seems simple to learn compared to react-native sqlite examples.

https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/